# locf and nocb function

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, locf

I would like to create a function using this as base:

```
locf <- function(x) {
  a <- x[1]
  for (i in 2:length(x)) {
    if (is.na(x[i])) x[i] <- a
    else a <- x[i]
  }
  return(x)
}
```

This function is just LOCF, I would like to create a function that is LOCF for all the missing data and NOCB for the first missing observation.

My data:

```
data<-c(NA, 24.107, NA, 26.912, NA, 30.193, NA, 19.003, NA, NA, 28.578, NA, NA, 33.484, 32.952, 13.574, NA, NA, 38.782, NA, NA, NA, 28.804, NA, 27.042, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21.344, NA, 21.507, NA, NA, NA, 16.508, NA, NA, 14.015, 11.738, 15.055)
```

What i want to obtain:

```
locf<-c(24.107, 24.107, 24.107, 26.912, 26.912, 30.193, 30.193, 19.003, 19.003, 19.003, 28.578, 28.578, 28.578, 33.484, 32.952, 13.574, 13.574, 13.574, 38.782, 38.782, 38.782, 38.782, 28.804, 28.804, 27.042, 27.042, 27.042, 27.042, 27.042, 21.344, 21.344, 21.507, 21.507, 21.507, 21.507, 16.508, 16.508, 16.508, 14.015, 11.738, 15.055)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are several functions to do just this. Here's one I wrote for the `MESS` package in Rcpp. First `filldown` then reverse the vector and run it again: `rev(MESS::filldown(rev(MESS::filldown(data))))`. You could even do the same double reverse trick with your own function.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to the first element of the list by "first missing observation", the following would work:

```
my_function <- function(my_list) {
  for(i in 1:length(my_list)) {
    if(is.na(my_list[i])) {
      if(i == 1) {
        my_list[i] <- my_list[i + 1]
      } else {
        print(i)
        my_list[i] <- my_list[i - 1]
      }
    }
  }
  return(my_list)
}
```

If you want to treat the first NA observation of the list differently regardless of its location (i.e. it may be third element of the list overall), you can tweak the function:

```
my_function <- function(my_list) {
  first <- 0
  for(i in 1:length(my_list)) {
    if(is.na(my_list[i])) {
      if(first == 0) {
        my_list[i] <- my_list[i + 1]
        first <- 1
      } else {
        print(i)
        my_list[i] <- my_list[i - 1]
      }
    }
  }
  return(my_list)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The fist code workd great for me!!! If I have different data like these: data<-c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 30.193, NA, 19.003, NA, NA, 28.578, NA, NA, 33.484, 32.952, 13.574, NA, NA, 38.782, NA, NA, NA, 28.804, NA, 27.042, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21.344, NA, 21.507, NA, NA, NA, 16.508, NA, NA, 14.015, 11.738, 15.055) and I want to obtain these:

Comment: data<-c(30.193, 30.193, 30.193, 30.193,  30.193, 30.193, 30.193, 19.003, 19.003, 19.003, 28.578, 28.578, 28.578, 33.484, 32.952, 13.574, 13.574, 13.574, 38.782, 38.782, 38.782, 38.782, 28.804, 28.804, 27.042, 27.042, 27.042, 27.042, 27.042, 21.344, 21.344, 21.507, 21.507, 21.507, 21.507, 16.508, 16.508, 16.508, 14.015, 11.738, 15.055) How can I modify the code? I'm still learning and I find difficult to understand how to modify the codes..Thank you!

Comment: you would not change anything...this is a function...you just change the input (just give another my_list to the function)

Answer (score 1):

This sets the first na to be the next value and then resets subsequent na’s by their locf values.

```
#library(zoo)
Nocb1.locf <- function (x){ wh1st <- which(is.na(x))[1]; 
   x[wh1st] <- x[wh1st + 1]
   x <- zoo::na.locf(x) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly this function exists in the **imputeTS** package:

```
library(imputeTS)
imputeTS::na.locf(x, option = "locf", na.remaining = "rev")
```

With the na.remaining parameter you can choose what shall be done with the remaining trailing NAs. You can for choose between "rev" (reverse), "mean" or "keep". Choosing "rev" does nocb for all NAs at the beginning that could not be filled by locf. If you choose to do option = "nocb" instead of "locf" in the first place it would of course then fill the trailing NAs with "locf".

Comment: Thank you! I know this function, but I don't know why I obtain a different imputation compared to my_function<- etc.

Comment: Think you are confusing this with the locf function of the package zoo. Try the exact code above it should give the same result.